# Add buttons with responses to an embed discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have been searching for an answer that works for my code, and I honestly cannot find one. I know how to create the buttons and add them to the bottom of my embed, but i cant get them to send a hidden message. This is my button code:

```py
buttons = [
  create_button(style=ButtonStyle.green, label="I liked it"), 
  create_button(style=ButtonStyle.grey, label="I'm neutral"), 
  create_button(style=ButtonStyle.red, label="I did not like it")
]
action_row = create_actionrow(*buttons)

bcc2 = await bcc.send(embed=embed, components=[action_row])
```

It is in a repeating function that occurs at a specific time a day. However, when I try to link the response, it just full on ignores it. Any recommendations? Here is my response attempt:

```
@slash.component_callback()
async def hello(ctx: ComponentContext):
    await ctx.send(content="You pressed a button!", hidden=True)
```

In the end I want the message sent to be a hidden message.

Comment: What package are you using to make the buttons and do slash commands? As far as I know, with `discord.py` you cannot send hidden messages. But some packages provide a way of sending an 'ephemeral message' as a response to slash commands and other components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this with discord.py, but you can do it with pycord, which is a fork of discord.py.
The newest version of pycord (2.0.0) supports slash commands, message components, and ephemeral messages.

You can install it by running this in your terminal:

```
pip install -U git+https://github.com/Pycord-Development/pycord
```

To make the bot send a hidden message, you do this:

```
await ctx.send('This is a hidden message', ephemeral=True)
```

You can also use the built in slash command feature with pycord, without needing to install a third-party library. You can check the docs [here](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/master/api.html) for more info.
[This tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kNUuYEWGOxA&ab_channel=CodeWithSwastik) explains how to create views and buttons with pycord.